# First attempt at a Pong game

Tags: java, game

This is my main class which handles the looping and setup of the game:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Thread thread;
    private Boolean running;

    public int width;
    public int height;

    protected static Boolean p1won, p2won;

    public static boolean gameover = false;

    private Player1 p1;
    private Player2 p2;
    private Ball ball;
    private Window window;

    public static boolean playing = false;

    public Game(){
        new Window(this, width, height, running);
        width = this.getToolkit().getScreenSize().width;
        height = this.getToolkit().getScreenSize().height;

        p1 = new Player1();
        p2 = new Player2();
        ball = new Ball(width, height, p1,p2, null, window);

        start();
    }

    private synchronized void start() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        running = true;
    }

    private synchronized void stop(){
        try {
            thread.join();
            running = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void run() {
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 100000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int frames = 0;
        while(running){
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while(delta >= 1){
                update();
                delta--;
            }
            if(running)
                render();
            frames++;

            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("FPS : "+frames);
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }

    private void update() {

        if(p1.score == 7){
            gameover = true;
            playing = false;
            p1.score = 0;
            p2.score = 0;
            p1won = true;
        } else if(p2.score == 7){
            gameover = true;
            playing = false;
            p1.score = 0;
            p2.score = 0;
            p2won  =true;
        }

        if(playing){
        p2.update(height);
        p1.update(height);

        ball.update(width, height);
        }
    }

    private void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null){//when a bufferedStrategy is gottn its default value is null
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);//gives the buffered strategy a value of three
            return;//returns the value so we don't create more buffered strategy's
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        Font f1 = new Font("Arial", 0, 150);
        Font f2 = new Font("Arial", 0, 50);

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getToolkit().getScreenSize().width, getToolkit().getScreenSize().height);

        if(!playing && gameover == false){

        g.setColor(Color.white);

        g.setFont(f1);
        g.drawString("PONG", width/2-250, height/5);

        g.setFont(f2);
        g.drawString("(Press Enter To Start)", width/2 - 250, height/2);
        g.drawString("Press ESCAPE to exit", width/2-250, height-400);
        }else if(playing && gameover == false){
            p2.render(g,width);
            ball.render(g);  
            p1.render(g,width);
            g.fillRect(width/2, 0, 25, 150);
            g.fillRect(width/2, height/100*20-150, 25, 150);
            g.fillRect(width/2, height/100*40-150, 25, 150);
            g.fillRect(width/2, height/100*60-150, 25, 150);
            g.fillRect(width/2, height/100*80, 25, 150);

        }
        else if(gameover == true && playing == false){
            g.setFont(f2);
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            if(p1won) g.drawString("Gameover Player 1 WON!", width/2-300, height/2);
            else if(p2won) g.drawString("Gameover Player 2 WON!", width/2-300, height/2);
        }

        bs.show();

    }

    public Window getWindow(){
        return window;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game();

    }

}
```

This handles the `Ball` movement and collision detection:

```
     import java.awt.Color;

    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Rectangle;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Ball {

    private Game game;
    private Player1 p1;
    private Player2 p2;

    private Random rand;


    int x;
    int y;

    int xa ;
    int ya ;

    public Ball(int width, int height, Player1 p1, Player2 p2, Game game, Window window){
        this.game = game;
        x = width/2;
        y = height/2;

        rand= new Random();

        xa = rand.nextInt(3)+1;
        ya = rand.nextInt(3)+1;

    }

    public void update(int width, int height){

        if(y<=0 || y>= height - 25)ya = ya *-1;
        if((x + 25 >= width - 150 && x <= width - 125 ) && (y >= p2.y && y <= p2.y +150 || y + 25 >= p2.y && y + 25 <= p2.y + 150))xa =rand.nextInt(2) - 4;
        if((x >= 150 && x <= 175) && (y >= p1.y && y <= p1.y + 150 || y + 25 >= p1.y && y + 25 <= p1.y + 150 )){
            xa =rand.nextInt(4);
            ya = rand.nextInt(4);
        }

        x += xa;
        y += ya;

        checkScoreCollision(width, height);
    }

    private void checkScoreCollision(int width, int height) {
        if(x <= 5){
            p2.score++;
            ballReset(width, height);
        }
        else if(x+26 >= width-5){
            p1.score++;
            ballReset(width, height);
        }
    }

    private void ballReset(int width, int height) {

        x = width/2;
        y = height/2;

        xa = rand.nextInt(4)-2;
        ya = rand.nextInt(4)-2;

        if(xa == 0 || ya == 0)ballReset(width, height);

    }


    public void render(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 25, 25);
    }

}
```

The `Window` class sets up the framing for the game:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends Canvas{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Player1 p1;

    public Window(Game game, int Height, int Width, Boolean playing){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pong");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(game);

        frame.addKeyListener(new KeyInput(playing));//add this shit to the frame you twat (spent 3-4 hours trying to figure thius out)
        frame.setFocusable(true);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Player1 getPlayer1(){
        return p1;
    }

}
```

The `KeyInput` class handles all the input:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class KeyInput implements KeyListener{

    private Game game;
    private Player1 p1;
    private Player2 p2;

    public KeyInput(Boolean playing){
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_R && Game.gameover == true){
            Game.playing = true;
            System.out.println(Game.playing);
            Game.gameover = false;
            Game.p1won = false;
            Game.p2won = false;  
        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && Game.playing == false && Game.gameover == false) Game.playing = true;
        else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && Game.playing == true) Game.playing = false;


        //player ones movement
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W)p1.up = true;
        else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S) p1.down = true;

        //player two's movement
                if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)p2.up = true;
                else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) p2.down = true;
    }     

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        Player1.down = false;
        Player1.up = false; 
        Player2.down = false;
        Player2.up = false; 
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

}
```

Player 1:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Player1 {

    public static int x = 150;
    public static int y = 500;
    public static int score = 6;
    public String scorestr;

    static Boolean up = false;
    static Boolean down = false;


    public void update(int height){
        if(y<=height  - 150)if(down)y += 2;
        if(y>= 0)if(up)y -= 2;
    }
    public void render(Graphics g, int width){
        //scoreStr = score;
        Font f1 = new Font("Arial", 0, 150);
        g.fillRect(150, y, 25, 150);
        scorestr = Integer.toString(score);
        g.setFont(f1);
        g.drawString(scorestr, width /2 -150, 150);
    }

}
```

Player 2:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Player2 {

    public static int y = 500;

    public static int score;
    public String scorestr;

    static Boolean up = false;
    static Boolean down = false;

    public void update(int height){
        if(y<=height  - 150)if(down)y += 3;
        if(y>= 0)if(up)y -= 3;
    }
    public void render(Graphics g, int width){
        scorestr= Integer.toString(score);
        Font f1 = new Font("Arial", 0, 150);
        g.setFont(f1);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(width- 150, y, 25, 150);
        g.drawString(scorestr, width /2 + 150, 150);
    }

}
```

I want to learn as much from this as I can so be brutally honest and try to highlight a few positives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Players

Why do you have a class for `Player1` and `Player2`. Refactor this into a `Player` class.

## Collision Detection

Your collision detection is not a good approach. You have `Ball` detect collisions. I would move that logic to either `Game` or some other sort of class who's purpose is to detect collisions.

[See this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/13031):

> The usual approach for collision detection is to not have either A or B detect collisions on their own.

Yet you have `Ball` do it's own work.

> Instead, you first move all objects, then have a separate collision system look for collisions between all pairs of objects, telling every object about the things that it has collided with, and then finally render all objects.

`Ball` could have a method like `collided(who)`, but the point is, that `Game` figures out when to call this method, and `Game` *tells* the `ball` `who`. The ball should not figure any of this out.

*To reiterate*: The `ball` should not determine whether it collided or not, the game should instead tell `Ball`: "Hey buddy, you collided" and the `Ball` should respond to this.